# external VBScript in a HTA

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am trying to get my HTA to load a script from an external location to save me releasing new HTA files, some of it can be loaded dynamically as I continue to add new functions to it. I can get it to work when I am using IIS to host the script file locally on my PC. But when I am trying to host it externally (I have only tried GitHub so far) I get the following error:

- Line: 1
- Char: 1
- Error: "Type mismatch: 'Hello'"
- Code: 0
- URL:

I have something like:

```
<html>

<HEAD>

<title>HTA Test</title>

<HTA:APPLICATION
     SCROLL="yes"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
     WINDOWSTATE="maximize"
>

<script language="VBScript" src="http://localhost/HtaUpdates/script.txt"></script>


<SCRIPT Language=vbscript>
Sub Window_OnLoad
    setTimeout "Hello", 100, "VBScript"
 End Sub

</SCRIPT>

</HEAD>
<BODY>

</BODY>

</html>
```

and in the script.txt on the server:

```
Sub Hello
    MsgBox("Hello.")
End Sub
```

Comment: The script path looks weird as this being hosted at GitHub ...?

Comment: `src="http://localhost/..."` will only work if you're publishing the file you want to load with a webserver running on localhost. Try a `file:///` URL, or simply a relative path.

Comment: @Nathan I have given you a detailed answer. Please let me know if it works for you, by leaving a comment on it or marking it as Accepted if it fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have two recommendations for you.

Firstly, the reason why the script isn't loading is because you're specifying the script as type 'txt'. This means when you serve the script over your local/remote web server, the MIME type for the script will be 'text/plain' which won't be accepted. If you rename it to be a proper 'vbs' extension, IIS will serve the file with the MIME type 'text/vbscript' which is what the HTA is expecting.

Additionally, using setTimeout in this way is fragile because it requires that your script contents are loaded successfully within 100ms. If the network is slow, the call will fail. It's better to simply make the call to `Hello` at the end of the script that you are requesting over the network. You could repurpose the setTimeout call to check if the script has loaded successfully within e.g. 10 seconds (by looking for a variable, maybe?) and show an error message if it hasn't. Note that in my solution below, I have put the main code *before* the script tag, so that the global variable `loaded` is visible to the remote script.

One final warning: While testing this, I found that the HTA was caching the VBS file so when I made changes to script.vbs, they weren't taking effect when I reloaded the application. You'd need to either...

- configure the web server to set an Expires header so that these files don't get cached
- write some code in your HTA file to request the script with a 'nonce' value after it, to override the cache. For example requesting `http://localhost/script.vbs?nonce=[RANDOM NUMBER]`, using VBScript's `Randomize` and `Rnd` functions. Requesting a static file with a nonce like this will still work on IIS because the parameters are ignored - it only cares that the file exists.

test.hta:

```
<html>
<HEAD>
<title>HTA Test</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION SCROLL="yes" SINGLEINSTANCE="yes" WINDOWSTATE="maximize">
<SCRIPT Language=vbscript>
    Dim loaded : loaded = False

    Sub CheckLoaded()
        If loaded Then
            MsgBox("Yes, the script loaded.")
        Else
            MsgBox("Oh dear! The script hasn't loaded.")
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub Window_OnLoad
        setTimeout "CheckLoaded", 1000, "VBScript"
    End Sub
</SCRIPT>
<script language="VBScript" src="http://localhost/script.vbs"></script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</html>
```

script.vbs:

```
loaded = True
MsgBox("Hello.")
```

Comment: Changing the file extension has not seemed to help when hosting on a site like raw.github.Testing to ensure that the external file has loaded before calling a function is a good idea and works great when I am using my local IIS to host the file. I'll have a bit more of a tinker and see what else I can try.

Comment: @Nathan You need to look at what's being returned by the Github server when you request that raw file. If the MIME type is not `text/vbscript` then it simply won't work, and you'll need to host a solution that can do so.